# How to access OAuth 2.0, REST API in GNOME 3.0 shell extension?

Tags: javascript, rest, gnome-shell-extensions, oauth2client

How would I port the OAuth 2.0 implict grant flow from a browser environment if I wanted to access the REST API beneath it through a GNOME shell extension ? 
How would I redirect the user to the OAuth 2.0 decision endpoint through a login screen?

If it isn't possible with a OAuth 2.0 REST API in what other way can I integrate a web service with a shell extension?